# Почему не записывается новое значение в глобальную переменую?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, ecmascript

```js
var arr = ["V", "l", "a", "d", "i", "m", "i", "r"];

var join = function (x) {
  return window.x = x.join('');
}

join(arr);

console.log(arr);
```

Вопрос стоит так, нужно получить именно новую переменную **arr**,которая в функции записывается глобально, а не параметр функции.

Comment: `console.log(window.x);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тоже отбитый вариант

```js
var arr = ["V", "l", "a", "d", "i", "m", "i", "r"];

var join = function(x) {
  for (var key in window)
    if (window[key] == x)
      window[key] = x.join('');
}

join(arr);

console.log(arr);
```

Не особо правильно конечно но

```js
var arr = ["V", "l", "a", "d", "i", "m", "i", "r"];

var join = function (x) {
  window[x] = window[x].join('');
}

join("arr");

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: спасибо, второй варинт как раз перезаписывает глобально перменую arr, а как  то будет особо правильно?

Comment: Этот код перестанет работать если собрать его вебпаком...

Comment: @Владимир Владимирович не особо правильно потому-что в качестве аргумента эта функция принимает строку а не саму переменную

Answer (score 5):

Такой код плохой, так как

```
var join = function (x /* аргумент */) {
  return window.x /* глобальная переменная */ = x.join('');
}
```

идёт путаница с `x`, в одном месте это название параметра в другом глобальная переменная. Конечно сам код запустится и скомпилируется, но таково кода следует избегать так как его сложно читать и сложно отлаживать.

Так же таких конструкций тоже желательно избегать

```
return window.x = x.join('');
```

лучше сделать отдельными операциями (одна строчка на одну операцию или группу операций единых по смыслу) что бы более была ясна суть, это конечно не ошибка

рекомендую делать так

```
window.x = x.join('');
return window.x;
```

Заметим что результат попадает в возвратку функции и в `x` глобальную переменную, поэтому что бы вывести этот результат в консоль оттуда и надо брать

```
console.log(x);
```

или

```
var rez = join(arr);
console.log(rez);
```

итого

```js
var arr = ["V", "l", "a", "d", "i", "m", "i", "r"];

var join = function(arr) {
  window.x = arr.join('');
  return window.x;
}

join(arr);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Полянин, вопрос стоит, что нужно получить именно новую переменную arr,которая в функции записывается глобально, а не параметр функции, нужно чтобы при использовании функции , переменная перезаписывалась. Спасибо за совет в оформлении. НО я не то хотел, следующий ответчик меня понял лучше

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович В моём коде так и происходит `window.x = arr.join('');` если нужно именно в arr записать то делаете `window.arr = arr.join('');` внутри функции либо `arr = join(arr);` снаружи. Но и этот код некрасивый, желательно в одной переменной хранить всегда один тип значения, а не так что сначала массив, потом строку, так как это рождает путаницу.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ["V", "l", "a", "d", "i", "m", "i", "r"];

var join = function (x) {
  return window.x = x.join('');
}

join(arr);

console.log(x); // <- ошибка
```